# Identity server 4 with .Net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am trying to use Identity server with .Net Core 2.0 and I am following this guide for that: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html

I created the Identity server application as per the above link and hosted with 5000 port and also registered a user.

I took client application from the samples and when I click on Secure, it is showing me the Login page of the application which is hosted on 5000 but after clicking on Login nothing is happening.

[image]

It is throwing 404 error. Can anyone suggest what am I missing?

Comment: Can you please check if the QuickStart codebase you are using has a ConsentController?

Comment: Nope @AbhaySaraf that is what I am wondering that it is not mentioned anywhere here in this link to add that controller http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html. Do you know any samples for that?

Comment: The key difference is that the quickstart has `RequireConsent` set to false, thus avoiding the need for `ConsentController`. The Quickstart.UI project has [everything you need](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/tree/release/Quickstart/Consent).

Comment: @Neel you will find the reference to Consent in the [docs here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/consent.html). Kirk Larkin has posted the link to code as well

Comment: Have you cloned the Quickstart UI code from https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/tree/release? If not then you are missing a number of controllers/options/services/pages which you will need to then setup manually.

Answer (score 0):

As determined in the comments, you need to add Consent related code to your project. The docs are [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/consent.html) and sample codebase in QuickStarts is [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/tree/release/Quickstart/Consent).